# How to print images in a grid formate using fpdf

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation, fpdf, php-extension

I am working on an application and I have generated reports via php fpdf library. I am stuck on the part to print images in grid view. I am unable to figure a way out. I'm first time using this library so I couldn't find any solution regarding this. Any help will be appreciated. I have attached an image of desired results.[image]

Comment: Should have a look at bootstrap grid system. It will help

Comment: Thanks Aman Jaura. I have made this bootstrap already. I want this to be displayed in fpdf exactly like this.

Comment: Please vote up if you think the answer requires some research. Aman Jaura.

Comment: Manually, calculate the positions and output an the element (image, text, line) at this position.

Answer (score 0):

You can try bootstrap 4 Grid view
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

use thumbnail or card.

Comment: Arvin thanks. I want to print it in fpdf. Not in bootstrap. I already done that part. I need a solution to print this grid in fpdf.